# Round-cap lines used in a SVG pattern

Tags: svg

Currently using an SVG `<pattern>` element with a bunch of `<line>` elements will cause it to have a sort of tapered-off edge. I've tried a bunch of different CSS stylings to get around this, but nothing's really worked. Here's the code to a circle with a stitch masked on it:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height="500" width="500">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="stripe" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="20" height="20">
      <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="20" y2="20" />
    </pattern>
    <mask id="mask">
      <rect height="500" width="500" style="fill: url(#stripe)" />
    </mask>
    <style>
      #stripe line {
        fill: white;
        stroke: white;
        stroke-linecap: square;
        stroke-linejoin: miter;
        stroke-width: 10px;
      }
      g {
        mask: url(#mask);
        stroke-linecap: square;
        stroke-linejoin: miter;
      }
      circle {
        fill: green;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <g>
    <circle cx="250" cy="250" r="200" style="fill: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2);" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

And here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpKZB/) of what this looks like. No combination of `stoke-linecap` and `stroke-linejoin` has worked for me. Do I instead need to draw a full `<path>` across the entire mask?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Woo! What a ride.

After seeing Duopixel's answer, I got started on a trail. I didn't know it was possible to achieve this effect until I understood the bounding box that applies to patterns.

Googling brought me to [this mailing list answer](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/svg-developers/message/63599) which didn't make much sense at first until the original author returned with gained insight (sorry, too many links). I looked back at the answer and saw potential in solving this problem.

**Solution:**
You have to overlay two patterns on-top of eachother in the right coordinates!

**Code:** (demo - http://jsfiddle.net/66UDU/)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height="500" width="500">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="stripe1" class="stripe" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="20" height="20">
      <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="20" y2="20" />
    </pattern>
    <pattern id="stripe2" class="stripe" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="6" y="6" width="20" height="20">
      <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="20" y2="20" />
    </pattern>
    <mask id="mask">
      <rect height="500" width="500" style="fill: url(#stripe1)" />
      <rect height="500" width="500" style="fill: url(#stripe2)" />
    </mask>
    <style>
      .stripe line {
        fill: white;
        stroke: white;
        stroke-width: 4px;
      }
      g {
        mask: url(#mask);
      }
      circle {
        fill: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.25);
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <g>
    <circle cx="250" cy="250" r="200" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

=)

Answer (score 8):

Well I know that this answer isn't far off 2 years late, but I stumbled across this question while researching another problem and thought I'd throw in my 2 cents for anyone who might come across it.

The problem here is as highlighted by Duopixel: the pattern just doesn't tile right.

Your solution certainly masks the problem by overlaying two non-tiling patterns to hide the non-tiling corners, but if you make the pattern wider and add additional lines offset from one another, and offset so as to ensure they never overlap a corner of the tile you can create a functioning pattern. You can up the stroke width on this all the way up without any problems with the corners.

```
<pattern id="stripe" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="40" height="20">
  <line x1="-10" y1="0" x2="10" y2="20" />
  <line x1="10" y1="0" x2="30" y2="20" />
  <line x1="30" y1="0" x2="50" y2="20" />
</pattern>
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sqrz3/)

I actually like the pattern made by the original problem though! I might have to find a use for it somewhere :)

Comment: This is the most elegant answer. 
For those interested in the pattern only (not the circle and mask), I've put a simplified version here with patterns going in either direction (either down or up): http://jsfiddle.net/wT22Y/

Answer (score 3):

That's an interesting problem. It looks like a line-cap issue but the actual problem is that the line corners of your pattern lie outside of the coordinates. Here is a diagram to understand what is happening:

[image]

You can either make the pattern larger with  `<pattern id="stripe" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="30" height="30">` or move the coordinates of your lines. In a cursory search I couldn't find any directive that would allow your pattern to overlap or display the overflow, but someone else might know of a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I'm particularly looking to display the overflow with the end goal being a striped pattern of variable width via stroke-width.

Comment: I have a solution, but unfortunately I'm unable to post it for another 10 hours or whatever. Until then, here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/66UDU/

Answer (score 0):

The post is old, but as I searched for a solution maybe someone also needs another solution like me.
As described above, a diagonal pattern has problems, thats why I created a straight horizontal line pattern and tranformed it with `patternTransform="rotate(45)"`.
Then only 1 `<line />` is needed instead of 2 overlapping ones.

Example:

```
<pattern id="stripe45" className="stripe-pattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternTransform="rotate(45)" width=".2" height=".2">
      <line x1="0" y1=".1" x2=".2" y2=".1" />
    </pattern>
```