# Simple fill pattern in svg : diagonal hatching

Tags: svg

How would I fill an SVG shape, not with a single colour, an image or a gradient, but with a hatching pattern, diagonal if possible.

It's been 2 hours and I've found nothing (at least after 2005).

I figure a possible hack would be a hatched PNG that would serve as fill, but that is not ideal.

Comment: People still looking for a solution to diagonal hatching might want to start here instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22401717/1717535

Comment: Here is a great fiddle i found doing this 
http://jsfiddle.net/h5NMP/

Answer (score 168, accepted):

I did not find anything for diagonal hatching on the internet either, so I'll share my solution here:

```
<pattern id="diagonalHatch" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="4" height="4">
  <path d="M-1,1 l2,-2
           M0,4 l4,-4
           M3,5 l2,-2" 
        style="stroke:black; stroke-width:1" />
</pattern>
```

(note the lower case `"l"` in the path expression)

The above creates a hatch with diagonal lines from the lower left to the upper right that are 4 pixels apart. Besides the diagonal line (`M0,4 l4,-4`) you also have to stroke the upper left and the lower right edges of the pattern area, since the line will otherwise be "constricted" due to clipping where it intersects the edges of the square.

[image: Example of a pattern after applying the above steps, it shows how the pattern it titled to make the end product]

To fill a rectangle with this pattern, do:

```
<rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#diagonalHatch)"/>
```

Comment: I had to add a style to the path in the pattern, for it to become visible:  for example(like akarve): style="stroke:black; stroke-width:1"

Comment: When I tried to enlarge this pattern to 20 x 20 px (with 8px stroke) and tested the result at higher zoom, the corner clipping "string of sausages" effect appeared. I was able to fix it by making the corner lines longer, e.g. `M 0 0 L 20 20 M 10 -10 L 30 10 M -10 10 L 10 30`.

Comment: The "string of sausages" effect might be caused by anti-aliasing. Try adding `shape-rendering="cripsEdges"`.

Comment: @Ingo Kegel Forgive me for asking but I can't find an explanation online, how would I change the parameters to have distance of 10 rather than 4?

Comment: Change the path to `M-1,1 l2,-2 M0,10 l10,-10 M9,11 l2,-2`

Comment: Thanks! This was such a simple solution. I can also easily change `stroke:black` to `stroke:#386cb0`. But how do I change the background?

Comment: > But how do I change the background?
you can add a rect element of the same size as the pattern (width and height 100%) before the path and set its fill to the color you want

Answer (score 96):

Use the patternTransform attribute to rotate a vertical (or horizontal) line segment. This method tiles seamlessly and uses the simplest possible path. The pattern `width` attribute controls how close parallel hatches are.

```
<pattern id="diagonalHatch" width="10" height="10" patternTransform="rotate(45 0 0)" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="10" style="stroke:black; stroke-width:1" />
</pattern>
```

Comment: Best solution so far: simple (no complex geometry) and flexible (any rotation angle can be set and the `width` pattern attribute sets the gap between the stripes). To make it even simpler, I would use `<line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="2" style="stroke:black; stroke-width:1" />` in lieu of `<g>...</g>`.

Comment: simplified code sample to use <line>, added clarification on use of width. good catches.

Comment: I love this solution, but there is currently a bug in FF (v 31.0, OSX). When you rotate the pattern, little white lines appear.

Comment: Hi Jason, I've seen that bug. You can try playing with the size of the pattern, making it larger than the space it fills, if I recall.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to set the background color of the rectangle that uses this pattern?

Comment: @YannicKlem to set a background color, add `<rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" style="fill:skyblue"/>` before the `<line/>`.

Comment: Even simpler: Use `<rect>` instead of `<line>`, and make your pattern size 10x1 instead of 10x10.

Comment: Using `<rect>`, you can set floating point widths e.g. `width="0.5"` for thin lines.

Answer (score 18):

This code from http://bl.ocks.org/jfsiii/7772281 seems very clean and reusable:

```css
svg {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

rect.hbar {
  mask: url(#mask-stripe)
}

.thing-1 {
  fill: blue;
}


.thing-2 {
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <title>SVG colored patterns via mask</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <svg>
          <defs>
            <pattern id="pattern-stripe" 
              width="4" height="4" 
              patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
              patternTransform="rotate(45)">
              <rect width="2" height="4" transform="translate(0,0)" fill="white"></rect>
            </pattern>
            <mask id="mask-stripe">
              <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#pattern-stripe)" />
            </mask>      
          </defs>
    
          <!-- bar chart -->
          <rect class="hbar thing-2" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="100"></rect>
          <rect class="hbar thing-2" x="51" y="50" width="50" height="50"></rect>
          <rect class="hbar thing-2" x="102" y="25" width="50" height="75"></rect>
          
          <!-- horizontal bar chart -->
          <rect class="hbar thing-1" x="0" y="200" width="10" height="50"></rect>
          <rect class="hbar thing-1" x="0" y="251" width="123" height="50"></rect>
          <rect class="hbar thing-1" x="0" y="302" width="41" height="50"></rect>
          
        </svg>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 16):

You may be able to create, what you want using a `<pattern>` tag.

As a starting point you might take this example of [the respective MDN docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG/Element/pattern):

```html
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120"
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
     
        <defs>
            <pattern id="Triangle"
                     width="10" height="10"
                     patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <polygon points="5,0 10,10 0,10"/>
            </pattern>
        </defs>
     
        <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="50"
                fill="url(#Triangle)"/>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was missing patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse". Without it my pattern did not appear at all.

Answer (score 9):

One problem with drawing a diagonal line within a pattern is that when the pattern is tiled the lines won't always line up - especially at high zooms. (It depends on the SVG rendering engine you happen to be using).
@Ingo's answer above attempts to resolve this by drawing in the triangles at the top-left and bottom-right corners - but again, using some rendering engines and high zooms, it doesn't always look best - and sometimes the line ends up looking a bit like a string of sausages.

Another approach is to draw a horizontal line in the pattern and rotate the pattern, e.g.

```
  <svg:svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1"
xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<svg:defs>
  <svg:pattern id="diagonalHatch" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="4" height="4" patternTransform="rotate(45 2 2)">
    <svg:path d="M -1,2 l 6,0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1"/>
  </svg:pattern>
</svg:defs>
<svg:rect x="0" y="0" height="100" width="100" fill="url(#diagonalHatch)"/>
```

Comment: +1 from me, I found if I wasn't using the svg namespace prefix that I needed to make sure I used <patter> rather than <svg:pattern>

Answer (score 9):

These two resources are very helpful:
https://bocoup.com/weblog/using-svg-patterns-as-fills
https://github.com/iros/patternfills/blob/master/public/patterns.css

For example:

```
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='10' height='10'>
  <rect width='10' height='10' fill='red'/>
  <path d='M-1,1 l2,-2
           M0,10 l10,-10
           M9,11 l2,-2' stroke='orange' stroke-width='2'/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 5):

I tried with this sample. Hopefully, It can help you much.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>SVG colored patterns via mask</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 300 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <defs>
        <pattern id="stripes" viewBox="0,0,8,8" width="16" height="16" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
          <polygon points="0,0 4,0 0,4" fill="yellow"></polygon>
          <polygon points="0,8 8,0 8,4 4,8" fill="yellow"></polygon>
          <polygon points="0,4 0,8 8,0 4,0" fill="green"></polygon>
          <polygon points="4,8 8,8 8,4" fill="green"></polygon>
        </pattern>
      </defs>
   <rect fill="url(#stripes)" x="150" y="20" width="100" height="50" />
      <circle cx="50"  cy="50" r="50" fill="url(#stripes)"/>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Regards,
Vu Phan

Answer (score 4):

This is a solution for diagonal lines using circle in pattern. You can change angle as per your requirements.

```
<svg width="500" height="500">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="transformedPattern"
            x="0" y="0" width="2" height="20"
            patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            patternTransform="rotate(45)">

            <circle cx="1" cy="1" r="2" style="stroke: none; fill: #0000ff" />
        </pattern>
    </defs>

    <rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100"
        style="stroke: #000000; fill: url(#transformedPattern);" />
</svg>
```

Comment: this worked really well and was simple to edit. Is there a way to do a two color hatching? Eg. with a primary stripe color and a background color?

Answer (score 3):

Some great points got lost in the comments, so I wanted to aggregate that knowledge with some simpler inline examples. As far as I can tell, what method you choose to use is entirely up to preference since the heavy lifting is being done by `patternTransform` + `rotate` either way, but personally I think the `<rect>` method is easier to digest at-a-glance even if it might make more semantic sense to use `<line>`.

---

#### SVG Non-Scaling Pattern with `<rect>`

Define the spacing between your lines with the `<pattern>`'s `width`, and the width of the lines themselves via the nested `<rect>`'s width.

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/mandynicole/pen/GRGRLPN) as full-size background.

```html
<svg height="100%" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <pattern id="diaHatch" width="9" height="1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternTransform="rotate(45)">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="3" height="1" fill="red" />
  </pattern>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#diaHatch)" />
</svg>
```

---

#### SVG Non-Scaling Pattern with `<line>`

Define the spacing between the `<line>`s with the `pattern` `height`, and use `stroke-width` for the `<line>` itself.

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/mandynicole/pen/MWXWdrM) as full-size background.

```html
<svg height="100%" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <pattern id="diaHatch" width="1" height="9" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternTransform="rotate(45)">
    <line x1="0" x2="100%" y1="0" y2="0" stroke-width="9" stroke="black" />
  </pattern>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#diaHatch)" />
</svg>
```

---

#### On SVG 2 & Hatches [as of October 2022]

While the above examples solve the issue, [SVG 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/)'s [Hatches](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/CR-SVG2-20160915/pservers.html#Hatches) (Candidate Recommendation 2016) are a documented method of tackling this exact issue. Inkscape happens to implement them because one of its developers, Tavmjong Bah, was an Invited Expert at the time, but browsers are still tackling them. To note, the latest [Editor's Draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/pservers.html) (2018) doesn't include `hatch`, which doesn't necessarily mean anything, but might be why it hasn't yet been prioritized by browser vendors.

---

#### Tracking SVG 2 Features for the Browser

Each major engine has an ongoing thread for feature implementations:

- [SVG 2 in Gecko](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1328534)
- [SVG 2 in Blink](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=225863)
- [SVG 2 in Webkit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=191292)

Answer (score 2):

SVG 2 has a [`hatch` entity](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-SVG2-20150915/pservers.html#Hatches) for specifically this purpose. From that page's example section:

```
<hatch hatchUnits="userSpaceOnUse" pitch="5" rotate="135">
  <hatchpath stroke="#a080ff" stroke-width="2"/>
</hatch>
```

This is a very easily configurable way to create hatches:

[image: Illustration of hatch tag from the w3c]

Furthermore the [hatch path](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-SVG2-20150915/pservers.html#Hatchpaths) can also be customised:

```
<hatchpath stroke-width="1" d="C 0,4 8,6 8,10 8,14 0,16 0,20"/>
```

Comment: Well it does but nobody's actually implemented it have they?

Comment: @RobertLongson Well, I mostly use svg as an intermediate format and compile it to pdf (I use inkscape as a compiler, for example). And inkscape certainly implements it, although it might not emit such code on its own. You are correct that firefox fails to correctly implement hatches. I don't know about other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

For React Native use can use this component, for making background lines pattern.
You should add to your project [react-native-svg](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg)

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import Svg, { Defs, Line, Pattern, Rect } from 'react-native-svg';

export default class PatternLineView extends PureComponent {

  static propTypes = {
    pattern: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    space: PropTypes.number,
    backgroundColor: PropTypes.string,
    lineColor: PropTypes.string,
    lineWidth: PropTypes.number,
    rotation: PropTypes.number
  }

  static defaultProps = {
    pattern: () => { },
    space: 8,
    lineColor: "#D2D9E5",
    lineWidth: 3,
    rotation: 45
  }

  render() {
    const transform = `rotate(${this.props.rotation})`
    return <View style={{
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: "row",
      height: "100%",
      width: "100%",
      position: "absolute",
      top: 0,
      start: 0,
      backgroundColor: this.props.backgroundColor
    }}>
      <Svg width="100%" height="100%">
        <Defs>
          <Pattern
            id="linePattern"
            patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            patternTransform={transform}
            width={this.props.space}
            height={this.props.space}>
            <Line
              x1="0"
              y1="0"
              x2="0"
              y2="100%"
              stroke={this.props.lineColor}
              strokeWidth={this.props.lineWidth}
            />
          </Pattern>
        </Defs>

        <Rect
          fill="url(#linePattern)"
          x="0"
          y="0"
          width="100%"
          height="100%"
        />
      </Svg>
    </View>
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks a ton. this helped me alot. 
Can you help me out to do the same in Android splash screen please?

Answer (score 0):

I've adapted [Ingo's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/936832/ingo-kegel) [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14500054/8915430).

```
<defs>
    <pattern id="diagonalHatch" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="4" height="4">
        <!-- background -->
        <path id="background"
            d="M-1,3 L3,-1
               M1,5 L5,1" style="stroke:pink; stroke-width:10" />
        <!-- hatches -->
        <path id="hatches"
            d="M-2,2 L2,-2
               M0,4 L4,0
               M2,6 L6,2" style="stroke:red; stroke-width:1" />
    </pattern>
</defs>
```

This pattern includes two paths, one for the background, and other for the hatches.  The background color is addressable vs JS such as:

`const hatchPath = document.querySelector("path#hatches");`

`hatchPath.setAttribute('style', "stroke:blue; stroke-width:1")`

The background path is overly-wide on purpose, so that there's no part of the pattern not at least covered by the background.  Meanwhile, the hatches can have their width tuned to change how thick the lines are.