# Using a fill pattern instead of colour with HighCharts

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

I've been looking at various ways to produce graphs in webapps and have found [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) particularly useful. The app needs to cater for colour blindness so I am looking at using patterns instead of fill colours - as described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069446/simple-fill-pattern-in-svg-diagonal-hatching).

Something like this needs to be in the `<defs>` section of the SVG:

```
<pattern id="triangles"  width="10" height="10" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <polygon points="5,0 10,10 0,10"/>
</pattern>
<pattern id="diagonal-hatch" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="4" height="4">
    <path d="M-1,1 l2,-2 M0,4 l4,-4 M3,5 l2,-2"/>
</pattern>
<pattern id="cross-hatch" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="6" height="6">
    <g style="fill:none; stroke:#22fa23; stroke-width:1">
        <path d="M0,0 l10,10"/>
        <path d="M10,0 l-10,10"/>
    </g>
</pattern>
```

and then instead of `fill="#0d233a"` I'd have `fill="url(#triangles)"`

Has anyone else done this with HighCharts?  Is it even possible to get HighCharts to do this without hacking it to pieces?

Comment: Have you tried it? It seems like normal SVG and that it SHOULD work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be a [pattern fill plugin](https://github.com/althaitran/highcharts-pattern-fill).

Comment: Thanks - that's what I'm after.

Comment: I can't make it work with wkhtmltopdf - did anyone had such issue?

Answer (score 4):

You can use Highcharts [plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/ErU8H/) for that. Topic is created [here](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/2378007-allow-fill-patterns-for-areas-columns-plot-bands).

For example patter for series:

```
{
    type: 'column',
    data: [148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6],
    color: {
        pattern: 'http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/pattern2.png',
        width: 6,
        height: 6,
        // VML only:
        color1: 'red',
        color2: 'yellow'
    }
}
```

Comment: awesome - thanks for this. I've done a [variation of the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/singingbush/8rkJh/) using some of the more funky patterns found on [philbit.com](http://philbit.com/svgpatterns)