# How to set a hatch pattern style in a svg

Tags: svg, background

I've written some SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>

<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

<svg width="100%" height="100%"  version="1.1"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<ellipse cx="150" cy="75" rx="100" ry="75" fill="rgb(200,240,120)" stroke="rgb(200,240,120)" stroke-width="3px" />
</svg>
```

It renders [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sw3Nj.png)

I want to convert the fill color render effect to [look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0MpL.png)

I have read the w3c document about SVG. I tried filter but It doesn't work like those images.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, the second image looks nothing like the first one? Also, the `fill` attribute is the color code for the fill.

Comment: the second image link was wrong,I've already fixed the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is called a "hatch pattern". Do a web search for how to do that in SVG.  Basically you need to define your hatch using the `<pattern>` element.

The following SO question may help you: [Simple fill pattern in svg : diagonal hatching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069446/simple-fill-pattern-in-svg-diagonal-hatching)

Note that the unfinished SVG2 standard defines a new [`<hatch>` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/pservers.html#Hatches) that will make creating hatch patterns a lot easier. However you cannot use this yet because no browser has implemented `<hatch>` yet.

Comment: I just wrote a bunch of pattern examples for SO docs: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/svg/3251/patterns#t=201608231352514242427

Comment: That's what I need. The document of SVG I read is version 1.0.It's a new feature in svg 2.0 version. Thank you very much. your answer is very helpfull to me.