# Striped fill for google line chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm trying to add a striped fill to my line chart, there seem to be an official solution for this https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/line_charts and they talk about chf.

However, I have no idea how to implement this, I've googled for it, and searched stackoverflow for a few hours now and can't seem to find a solution.

I need a striped fill like the even/odd css function.

```
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(Process1);

  function Process1() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4'],
      ['10',    400,      380,      48],
      ['20',    400,      340,      260],
      ['30',    400,      410,      310],
      ['40',    400,      390,      380],
      ['50',    400,      345,      345],
      ['60',    400,      385,      370],
      ['70',    400,      430,      410],
      ['80',    400,      null,         null],
      ['90',    400,      null,         null],
      ['100',   400,      null,         null],
      ['110',   400,      null,         null],
      ['120',   400,      null,         null]

    ]);

    var options = {
      theme: 'material',
      lineWidth: 3,
      colors: ['#3D3D3D', '#4CDD37', '#2076F2'],
      title: 'Orderinformation plan 1',
      titleTextStyle: {fontName:'Lato', fontSize:'20'},
      legend: { 
          position: 'right', 
         textStyle: {
              fontName:'Lato', fontSize:'12'
          },
      },        
      hAxis: {
            title: 'Time in minutes',
            titleTextStyle: {fontName:'Lato', fontSize:'16', italic:false},
          textStyle: {
              fontName:'Lato', fontSize:'16'
          },
      },
      vAxis: {
          title: 'Temperature in celsius',
          titleTextStyle: {fontName:'Lato', fontSize:'16', italic:false},
          textStyle: {
              fontName:'Lato', fontSize:'16'
          },
          viewWindowMode: 'explicit',
          ticks: [25,50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400,460],
          viewWindow: {
              max:460,
              min:25
          },
          gridlines: {
          count: 10
        }
      }
    };


    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart_1'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

Comment: the reference to the striped option is for the now deprecated image chart library, which is different from the chart library being used in the snippet above -- there are no standard options for striped fill

Comment: Ok, do you know if there is a way to do this in a none-standard-way?

Comment: it's possible to modify the chart's svg elements, once the `'ready'` event fires (lines will be `<path>`)  -- but changes made in this manner will not show if using `getImageURI` to produce an image of the chart -- [Simple fill pattern in svg: diagonal hatching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069446/simple-fill-pattern-in-svg-diagonal-hatching)...