# Pattern with three stripes

Tags: svg

I'm new to svg (and design in general) and looking for a way to fill a svg shape/path with three equally-sized diagonal stripes in different colors. For two stripes, I already found a solution on Stack Overflow ([Simple fill pattern in svg : diagonal hatching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069446/simple-fill-pattern-in-svg-diagonal-hatching)):

```
<svg width="300" height="30" viewBox="0 0 200 10">
    <pattern id="diagonalHatch" width="15" height="10" 
     patternTransform="rotate(135 0 0)" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
         <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="orange"></rect>
         <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="10" style="stroke:blue; stroke- 
          width:15" />
    </pattern>

    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#diagonalHatch)"/>
</svg>
```

I modified the solution somewhat, including a rectangle for background color (is there a better way to do this?). But I just can't figure out how to do it for three stripes. Another thing I also wondered is whether there is a way to pass the colors as some kind of parameters to the pattern, so that there is no need to declare multiple patterns just for color switching?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've added a second line to your pattern. Also I've removed the attributes with a value == 0. If your `stroke-width` is 10 (for example) you will need to begin your line at 5 since a line is drawn 5 units to one side and 5 to the other side. I hope it helps.

```html
<svg width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <pattern id="diagonalHatch" width="30" height="10" 
     patternTransform="rotate(130)" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
         <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="orange"></rect>
         <line x1="5" x2="5" y2="10" style="stroke:blue; stroke-width:10" />
         <line x1="15" x2="15" y2="10" style="stroke:red; stroke-width:10" />
    </pattern>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#diagonalHatch)"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is to create your stripes using a repeating linear gradient.

```html
<svg width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="diagonalHatch" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                    x2="30" spreadMethod="repeat" gradientTransform="rotate(-45)">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="orange"/>
      <stop offset="0.33" stop-color="orange"/>
      <stop offset="0.33" stop-color="blue"/>
      <stop offset="0.67" stop-color="blue"/>
      <stop offset="0.67" stop-color="red"/>
      <stop offset="1.0" stop-color="red"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#diagonalHatch)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: It was really helpful to find your example of a linearGradient that didn't use percentages. Works great as an alternative to using a pattern.