# SVG, ellipse with pattern does not show up

Tags: svg

The code below should generate a circle filled with a diagonal pattern. The code is taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069446), I just adapted the unit to get the following pattern: line thickness 0.2mm and line distance 1mm.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<svg baseProfile="full" height="3.2cm" version="1.1" 
  viewBox="0 0 5 3.2" width="5.0cm"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs />
  <pattern height="0.14142135623730953" id="#1"
    patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="0.14142135623730953">
    <path d="M-0.07071067811865477,0.07071067811865477
             l0.14142135623730953,-0.14142135623730953 
             M-0.07071067811865477,0.21213203435596428
             l0.28284271247461906,-0.28284271247461906
             M0.07071067811865477,0.21213203435596428
             l0.14142135623730953,-0.14142135623730953"
      style="stroke:black; stroke-width:0.02" />
  </pattern>
  <ellipse cx="2" cy="1.6" fill="url(#1)" id="#2" rx="1.5" 
    ry="1.5" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.01" />
  <ellipse cx="3" cy="1.6" fill="none" id="#3" rx="1.5" ry="1.5"
    stroke="none" stroke-width="0.01" />
  <text dominant-baseline="hanging" stroke="black" 
    text-anchor="end" x="0.5" y="0.7000000000000002">$A$</text>
  <text dominant-baseline="hanging" stroke="black" 
    text-anchor="start" x="4.5" y="0.7000000000000002">$B$</text>
</svg>
```

> Ignore the ellipse `#3` (it's transparent) and the two texts. Why does the ellipse `#2` not show up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this;

Your mistake is in naming id="#1"

if you select something by id you write #elementId

if you define element id you write id="elementId"

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<svg baseProfile="full" height="3.2cm" version="1.1" 
  viewBox="0 0 5 3.2" width="5.0cm"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs />
  <pattern height="0.14142135623730953" id="1"
    patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="0.14142135623730953">
    <path d="M-0.07071067811865477,0.07071067811865477
             l0.14142135623730953,-0.14142135623730953 
             M-0.07071067811865477,0.21213203435596428
             l0.28284271247461906,-0.28284271247461906
             M0.07071067811865477,0.21213203435596428
             l0.14142135623730953,-0.14142135623730953"
      style="stroke:black; stroke-width:0.02" />
  </pattern>
  <ellipse cx="2" cy="1.6" fill="url(#1)" id="#2" rx="1.5" 
    ry="1.5" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.01" />
  <ellipse cx="3" cy="1.6" fill="none" id="#3" rx="1.5" ry="1.5"
    stroke="none" stroke-width="0.01" />
  <text dominant-baseline="hanging" stroke="black" 
    text-anchor="end" x="0.5" y="0.7000000000000002">$A$</text>
  <text dominant-baseline="hanging" stroke="black" 
    text-anchor="start" x="4.5" y="0.7000000000000002">$B$</text>
</svg>
```