# Syntax for Inkscape vector hatch pattern

Tags: vector, inkscape

There are some Inkscape hatch patterns to download here:
https://github.com/zirafa/inkscape-hatch-patterns

Their syntax goes like this, for example:

```
<pattern id="Hatch1.0x135"
inkscape:stockid="Hatch 1.0 x -45°"
x="0" y="0" width="5.345059133378628" height="5.345059133378628"
patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
  <path
     style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.25mm"
     d="M 1.5655315743235096,-3.7795275590551185 9.124586692433747,3.7795275590551185"/>
  <path
     style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.25mm"
     d="M -3.7795275590551185,-3.7795275590551185 9.124586692433747,9.124586692433747"/>
  <path
     style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.25mm"
     d="M -3.7795275590551185,1.5655315743235096 3.7795275590551185,9.124586692433747"/>
</pattern>
```

...and creates a diagonal seamless hatch pattern looking like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMZ2u.png

However, these hatches are too coarse for my purpose, and maybe there is an easier syntax than the one used there?

Also, I can't make sense of these odd numbers. When I change them to something like:

```
<pattern id="MyPattern"
inkscape:stockid="MyPattern"
x="0" y="0" width="3" height="3"
patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
  <path
     style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.1mm"
     d="M 1,-3 9,3"/>
  <path
     style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.1mm"
     d="M -3,-3 9,9"/>
  <path
     style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.1mm"
     d="M -3,1 3,9"/>
</pattern>
```

...then the pattern doesn't tile seamlessly anymore, but looks like this instead:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fd60X.png

Or even like this, with somewhat changed numbers in the above code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7QuQ.png

I found something related here:
[Simple fill pattern in svg : diagonal hatching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069446/simple-fill-pattern-in-svg-diagonal-hatching)

So there seems to be a native hatch function in the SVG specification which should be easier than the tiling code of the above. However, I don't know whether or how this would be applicable to Inkscape.

Thankful for any ideas!