# Striped background in d3pie.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, pie-chart, d3pie.js

We're using d3pie[http://d3pie.org/#generator-result] a library over d3 to generate the Pie Chart and like to know how to replace the background in it with stripes.

If you look at the URL, http://d3pie.org/#generator-result, you can find that d3pie currently provides only three attributes related to the Data i.e. Label, Value and Color as below:

```
{
  "label": "Test",
  "value": 311,
  "color": "#d96d6d"
}
```

Not sure how to change the plain background color to look like stripes. Tried out Linear Gradients as in Css instead of Hexagonal Values for Color Attribute but that doesn't help.

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://riccardoscalco.github.io/textures/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use SVG `pattern` fill and `mask` to achieve this: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/wt45qfkz/2/

The `pattern` is borrowed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962077/round-cap-lines-used-in-a-svg-pattern/22401717#22401717) to a previous question.

Mask and pattern are applied to each individual pie slice using:

```
var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice")
  .data(pie).enter()
  .append("svg:g")
  .attr("class", "slice")
  .attr("style", "fill:url(#stripe);")
  .attr("style", "mask:url(#mask);");
```

However you may run in to trouble here when you add the label: If you put it into the same `g` element, the stripes will also be applied to the text